# antd: nested select/dropdown

Tags: drop-down-menu, antd

I'm trying to create a dropdown with nested layer.
Example:

[image]

I tried antd select OptGroup, but it's not supporting nested layers. I also tried antd TreeSelect, but the collapsible option is not good for my use case. Is there a way to show all nested selections without clicking?

Answer (score 0):

I think using antdesign Cascader seems better for your case.

Data structure:

```
const options = [
  {
    value: 'zhejiang',
    label: 'Zhejiang',
    children: [
      {
        value: 'hangzhou',
        label: 'Hangzhou',
        children: [
          {
            value: 'xihu',
            label: 'West Lake',
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },  
];
```

[image]

Comment: This still requires click multiple times to get to bottom layer. Is there an option just shows all layers without click